# create a jsp table using properties file

Tags: jsp, properties, jstl, el, resourcebundle

What is the best possible way to create a jsp table(key,value) from a properties file.

Right now I am doing this using scriptlets.....

```
    ResourceBundle statusCodes = ResourceBundle.getBundle("statuscode");    
Enumeration statusKeys = statusCodes.getKeys();


   <%
    while (statusKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) statusKeys.nextElement();
        String value = statusCodes.getString(key);
%>
<tr>
    <td><%=key%></td>
    <td><%=value%></td>
</tr>
```

NOTE: Dont worry about syntax this is not complete code.

How can I do this using EL and jstl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`java.util.Properties`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) instead of [`java.util.ResourceBundle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). The `ResourceBundle` serves an entirely different purpose and it should not be abused to have "an easy way" to load properties since it by default lookups resources from the classpath.

Let a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) load and prepare it for JSP.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/filename.properties"));
request.setAttribute("properties", properties);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/properties.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Because `Properties` implements `java.util.Map`, you can just use JSTL `<c:forEach>` to iterate over it. Every iteration gives a [`Map.Entry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) back which in turn has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods.

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${properties}" var="property">
        <tr>
            <td>${property.key}</td>
            <td>${property.value}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Finally invoke the servlet by its URL to get it to display.

Please note that `ResourceBundle` doesn't implement `java.util.Map`!